How to resolve AVAudioPlayer throwing Exception: "player did not see an IO cycle"
I have been wrestling with this problem for over a month now on Xamarin Forms iOS.
I'm writing an audio player which saves securityscoped urls into my own library stored in the sandbox. (The urls are picked from a UIDocumentPickerViewController and saved as MinimalBookmarks to NSData.)
When the user selects one of the bookmarks, the app:

Recovers the url from the NSData
Starts accessing the securityscoped resource
Copies the file to a temp file located in the sandbox
Creates an AVAudioFile from the temp file
Seeks to 2 secs into the file
Attempts to play, at which point the above exception is thrown

Strangely enough, when a user downloads the app from the App Store, it seems to work fine for a few hours.
After one or two hours the exception is consistently thrown and the only way to get the playback working again is to re-install from the App Store.
What might be the problem here?
Also note:

I have read articles suggesting this exception occurs when the device routes to another speaker, e.g. bluetooth speaker. This is not the case with my problem, as my user is always using the iPhone on-board speaker

My code is below with comments indicating observations I have made when analysing the problem:
AVAudioEngine engine;
AVAudioPlayerNode player;
AVAudioFile file;


void Play()   
{    
    AVAudioFormat format = null;
    bool restarted = false;
    NSUrl url = null;
    NSError err;
    string tempFile;

    try
    {
        url = UrlMgr.GetAudioNSUrl();

        if (url == null)
            return;

        if (UrlMgr.IsAudioUriSecurityScoped)
        {
            //this is fine, getting access never fails
            if (!url.StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource())
            {
                AppCenterMgr.TrackWarning("Play security error", true, "message");
                return;
            }
        }

        //get tempaudiopath copies the security scoped file into internal storage which 
        //is in the app sandbox. This never fails
        tempFile = GetTempAudioPath(url);
        file = new AVAudioFile(tempFile, out err);

        if (UrlMgr.IsAudioUriSecurityScoped)
            url.StopAccessingSecurityScopedResource();


        //these always give legitimate values indicating the 
        //AVAudioFile has been created successfully
        _lengthSamples = file.Length;
        format = file.ProcessingFormat;
        _sampleRate = format.SampleRate;

        //put this here just in case engine has been stopped unexpectedly
        //but this is never a problem, engine is always running
        if (!engine.Running)
            restarted = RestartEngine(true);

        SetAudioPlaybackPosition();

        //this works for a few hours, but after that fails repeatedly and 
        //thereafter never works again
        player.Play();

        //never reaches here
        timer.Start();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Objective-C exception thrown. Name: com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Reason: player did not see an IO cycle.
        AppCenterMgr.TrackError(e, "msg", e.Message, 
                                   "enginerunning", engine.Running, 
                                   "restarted", restarted,           //false
                                   "audiofilelen", file.Length);     //8691712 -> file seems to be valid

        if (UrlMgr.IsAudioUriSecurityScoped)
            url?.StopAccessingSecurityScopedResource();

    }
}

uint remainingSamples;
long startSample;
void SetAudioPlaybackPosition()
{
    //start playback 2 seconds in
    int time = 2000;

    startSample = (long)(time * _sampleRate / 1000);
    remainingSamples = (uint)(_lengthSamples - startSample);
    player.ScheduleSegment(file, startSample, remainingSamples, null, AVAudioPlayerNodeCompletionCallbackType.PlayedBack, OnEndReached);


}

public NSUrl GetTempAudioPath(NSUrl url)
{
    string path = null;
    FileInfo fi;

    using (FileStream s = new FileStream(url.Path.ToString(), FileMode.Open))
    {
        path = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "temp.mp3");

        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(path))
        {
            s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            s.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }

    }

    //check -> this never fails
    fi = new FileInfo(path);
    if (fi.Length < 100)
    {
        AppCenterMgr.TrackWarning("Small Audio File", false, "path", path, "len", fi.Length);
    }


    return new NSUrl(path);
}

MS App Center dump
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio Reason: player did not see an IO cycle. Native stack trace: 0 CoreFoundation 0x00000001a364cf2c 00E76A98-210C-3CB5-930B-F236807FF24C + 540460 1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000019b552018 objc_exception_throw + 60 2 CoreFoundation 0x00000001a374b66c 00E76A98-210C-3CB5-930B-F236807FF24C + 1582700 3 AVFAudio 0x00000001bd1c4198 A161186B-22A2-3A88-B6AE-3A022764AE54 + 16792 4 AVFAudio 0x00000001bd2b23a0 A161186B-22A2-3A88-B6AE-3A022764AE54 + 992160 5 AVFAudio 0x00000001bd1c4608 A161186B-22A2-3A88-B6AE-3A022764AE54 + 17928 6 AVFAudio 0x00000001bd2aea84 A161186B-22A2-3A88-B6AE-3A022764AE54 + 977540 7 Xamarin.Sdk 0x000000010ab95510 wrapper_managed_to_native_ObjCRuntime_Messaging_objc_msgSend_intptr_intptr_6 + 128 8 Xamarin.Sdk 0x000000010ab25964 AVFoundation_AVAudioPlayerNode_Play + 36 9 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001029e0324 sqlite3_sourceid + 4210204 10 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000102a724c0 sqlite3_sourceid + 4808632 11 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001029df924 sqlite3_sourceid + 4207644 12 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000102895598 sqlite3_sourceid + 2855056 13 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000102a623f8 sqlite3_sourceid + 4742896 14 MyApp.iOS 0x0000000102894fa4 sqlite3_sourceid + 2853532 15 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001028868b0 sqlite3_sourceid + 2794408 16 Xamarin.Sdk 0x000000010aaaded4 Foundation_NSAsyncActionDispatcher_Apply + 36 17 Xamarin.Sdk 0x000000010a1b49a0 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 272 18 Mono 0x000000010720fc4c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1136 19 Mono 0x00000001072ca41c mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 148 20 Mono 0x00000001072cdc5c mono_runtime_invoke + 144 21 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001027b9f2c sqlite3_sourceid + 1956388 22 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001027bede0 sqlite3_sourceid + 1976536 23 Foundation 0x00000001a2529aa4 3D3A12E3-F5E9-361F-B00A-4A5E8861AA55 + 740004 24 CoreFoundation 0x00000001a361f834 00E76A98-210C-3CB5-930B-F236807FF24C + 354356 25 CoreFoundation 0x00000001a361f7c8 00E76A98-210C-3CB5-930B-F236807FF24C + 354248 26 CoreFoundation 0x00000001a361d298 00E76A98-210C-3CB5-930B-F236807FF24C + 344728 27 CoreFoundation 0x00000001a361c484 00E76A98-210C-3CB5-930B-F236807FF24C + 341124 28 CoreFoundation 0x00000001a361bcd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608 29 GraphicsServices 0x00000001e84cc1a8 GSEventRunModal + 164 30 UIKitCore 0x00000001a5c5490c 1741FA37-4E53-371E-8DAE-D611AAB0043D + 4237580 31 UIKitCore 0x00000001a5d089d0 UIApplicationMain + 340 32 Xamarin 0x00000001066274d8 xamarin_UIApplicationMain + 24 33 Xamarin.Sdk 0x000000010ab90ac8 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_xamarin_UIApplicationMain_int_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr_ + 152 34 Xamarin.Sdk 0x000000010aae07bc UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 76 35 Xamarin.Sdk 0x000000010aae0960 UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___System_Type_System_Type + 224 36 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001029eb054 sqlite3_sourceid + 4254540 37 Xamarin.Sdk 0x000000010a1b49a0 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 272 38 Mono 0x000000010720fc4c mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1136 39 Mono 0x00000001072ca41c mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 148 40 Mono 0x00000001072d0724 mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 128 41 Mono 0x00000001071ed308 mono_jit_exec + 376 42 Xamarin 0x000000010663ab84 xamarin_main + 1064 43 MyApp.iOS 0x00000001027f65bc sqlite3_sourceid + 2203828 44 dyld 0x00000001c6ccde4c 71846EAC-EE65-3697-BF7D-790B6A07DCDB + 249420
